# Reading firebase data to answer Dialogflow query from Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

Thanks for your time in reading this query. I am implementing a Dialogflow bot using google cloud functions and firebase.

The use case, I wish to design is that 
User says "I wish to know information about New York"
Dialog flow captures the intent "lookingForInformation" with Geo.City parameter as "New York" and Action as getInfo.

I have set up Google cloud functions and integrated with Apiai as well as Firebase.

My Firebase Json looks like

```html
{
  information :
    {
      1 : 
      {
      destinationName : "New Jersey",
      DestinationInfo : "Its a nice place"
      },
      2 : 
      {
      destinationName : "London",
      DestinationInfo : "Its a lovely place"
      },
  
    }

}
```

My Google cloud function like this

```html
function processV1Request (request, response) {
  let action = request.body.result.action; // https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters
  let parameters = request.body.result.parameters; // https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters
  let inputContexts = request.body.result.contexts; // https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts
  let requestSource = (request.body.originalRequest) ? request.body.originalRequest.source : undefined;
  const googleAssistantRequest = 'google'; // Constant to identify Google Assistant requests
  const app = new DialogflowApp({request: request, response: response});
  // Create handlers for Dialogflow actions as well as a 'default' handler
  const actionHandlers = {
    // The default welcome intent has been matched, welcome the user (https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#default_welcome_intent)
    
    // Default handler for unknown or undefined actions
    'checkDestination': () =>{
      // Use the Actions on Google lib to respond to Google requests; for other requests use JSON
      if (requestSource === googleAssistantRequest) {
        let responseToUser = {
         
          speech: 'I wish to check destinations', // spoken response
          text: 'I wish to check destinations' // displayed response
        };
        sendGoogleResponse(responseToUser);
      } else {
        console.log(mySet);
        let responseToUser = {
          speech: 'I wish to check destinations', // spoken response
          text: 'I wish to check destinations' // displayed response
        };
        sendResponse(responseToUser);
      }
    
    },

   
  };
```

I wish to update the above cloud function above to query the firebase database, if the parameter geo.city exist as valid destination in my database. If yes, it should return the information from database, if 'No', it should respond with "Sorry, I don't have information about this city".

Warm Regards

Comment: Have you tried integrating and calling the firebase db at all? Or tried handling the `lookingForInformation' Intent, even to look at the parameters and return a static response? It looks like you just showed the boilerplate code.